# Trying to fill entire content box with background image

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to fill the content-right box with a background image using CSS properties. The problem is that that background image is not taking up the entire space. Can anybody explain why this is happening ?

I have tried to use the following:

.content-right {
object-fit: cover
}

I didn't get my desired result though.

```css
.landing-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}

.content-right,
.content-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--display-text);
  background-image: url(../img/swirl-background.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.content-right h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-light-grey);
  z-index: 10;

}

.content-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

```html
<section id="landing">
    <div class="landing-container">
      <div class="content-left">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, exercitationem!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis, perferendis soluta. Ex enim architecto
          laborum, totam sed voluptate, quasi voluptatem molestias voluptatum commodi vel beatae?</p>
        <button class="btn-primary">Discover More Now</button>
      </div>

      <div class="content-right">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, similique!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[image: Here is an example image of the desired outcome]

[image: Here is how the page looks]

Comment: give `margin : 0`  to your body

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately that did not solve it. I do have 

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

already been used.

Comment: can you please add live image url in background image

Comment: Can you please supply us with the desired result in a picture form. Atm, there seem to be several answers, but don't seem to be the solution for you.

Comment: @GhostPengy, I have added an example image of what the outcome i want to achieve would look like.

Comment: Is the issue when the page has a scroll bar? Or is the issue the small border around the image (body native browser margin)?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how the page looks exactly. As you can see there, the background image in not filling the full right-content box the way i am looking for it to be like from the the first image i uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact same layout, within which the right-column can adjust its width by its text (meaning, without overflowing the container), you can use a simply flexbox:

```css
.landing-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.content-right,
.content-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.content-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--display-text);
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/CGLPFcq.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content-right h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-light-grey);
  z-index: 10;
}

.content-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

```html
<section id="landing">
  <div class="landing-container">
    <div class="content-left">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, exercitationem!</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis, perferendis soluta. Ex enim architecto laborum, totam sed voluptate, quasi voluptatem molestias voluptatum commodi vel beatae?</p>
      <button class="btn-primary">Discover More Now</button>
    </div>

    <div class="content-right">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, similique!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If instead you'd like to make both columns exactly 50% of the parent container, just change [flex-shrink](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) to 0 (so in the code above, change `flex: 0 1 50%;` to `flex: 0 0 50%;`)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.landing-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}

.content-right,
.content-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--display-text);
  background-image: url("../img/swirl-background.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.content-right h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--color-light-grey);
  z-index: 10;

}

.content-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

```html
<section id="landing">
    <div class="landing-container">
      <div class="content-left">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, exercitationem!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Veritatis, perferendis soluta. Ex enim architecto
          laborum, totam sed voluptate, quasi voluptatem molestias voluptatum commodi vel beatae?</p>
        <button class="btn-primary">Discover More Now</button>
      </div>

      <div class="content-right">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, similique!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```